# Checking for Winner in Connect Four - Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, indexoutofboundsexception, 2d-games

I am creating a simple Connect Four program in Kotlin using a 2D array to print the board. Everything works fine except for my horizontal win-checker function. Because of the logic I am using, I get (index out of bounds) errors when trying to put your piece on the first column, because it is trying to check the next column in the array, but there is none. Is there a better way to handle checking for a winner? This is my function:

```
fun checkWinsHorizontal() {
    for(row in 0 until gameBoard.size) {
        for(col in 0 until gameBoard.size){
            // if this spot is taken up by an "X", and the horizontally adjacent spaces are the same, declare winner
            if (gameBoard[row][col] == "X" && (gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col - 1] && gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col - 2] && gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col - 3]) ){
                printBoard()
                println("YOU WIN")
                winner = true
                return
            }
            // same thing as above but for a "computer" opponent
            else if (gameBoard[row][col] == "O" && gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col - 1] && gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col - 2] && gameBoard[row][col] == gameBoard[row][col - 3]){
                printBoard()
                println("COMPUTER WINS")
                winner = true
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The index out of bound occurs because you iterate over the full length and you using precursors and successors. Furthermore: should the algorithm only check the horizontal win condition or also the vertical and diagonal win condition?

Comment: There's a few options. I'd probably refactor a bit, but as it stands, in the outer loop you could initialise a variable with the value of ganeBoard[row][0] then in the inner loop just compare each gameBoard[row][col] against that value. If any is different drop out the loop as there's no win. If you get to the end of the inner loop then the winner is the owner of the symbol in that variable

Answer (score 1):

The comments above explain why you're getting the index out of bounds (you have hard coded values like `gameBoard[row][col - 1]` but `col` might be 0). I suggest a few fixes:

First, there's no need to check every cell on the board after each move. The only way a player can win is if the piece they just placed completes a row, column, or diagonal. So I suggest you check only potential wins involving that cell.

To do that for a row you could have something like:

```
fun completesRow(row: Int, col: Int) : Boolean {
  var count: Int = 1
  val symbol = gameBoard[row][col]
  // First move left - now we check that the symbols (X or O) match
  // AND that we're within bounds.
  var curCol = col - 1
  while (curCol >= 0 && gameBoard[row][curCol] == symbol) {
    ++count
    if (count == 4) {
        return true
    }
    --curCol
  }

  // same thing to the right; numColumns is assumed to be the number of
  // columns in the board.
  curCol = col + 1
  while (curCol < numColumns && gameBoard[row][curCol] == symbol) {
    ++count
    if (count == 4) {
        return true
    }
    ++curCol
  }

  // if you got here there weren't 4 in a row
  return false
}
```

Note: the above is untested - I doubt it even compiles, but hopefully it's instructive.

You can also further generalize this if you want. Instead of having different functions that move left/right, up/down, and diagonally you could create `Iterator` instances for those movements and then have a single function that takes 2 iterators (one moving left and one right for example) and it can do the checks using that. That way you can use the same exact method to check a horizontal, vertical, or diagonal win.

Comment: Hello, this is super helpful and is definitely getting me back on track, but I do have a small question, as I haven't gotten much experience with boolean functions. It seems the second _while_ statement always returns true, do you have idea why this might be?

Comment: Both while statements return true if and only if the count of consecutive symbols is 4 meaning somebody won the game. For example, suppose the symbol the right of `col` doesn't match the one at `[row][col]`. Then the `while` statement should exit without returning `true` and you'd hit the line at the end of the function which returns `false`.

Comment: I did just notice a small bug and updated the code - `count` should have been initialized to `1` rather than `0` since the cell at `[row][col]` counts.

Comment: I understand that both statements are _supposed_ to return true when count is equal to 4. However, the second _while_ statement returns true as soon as it is called.

Comment: I'd have to see some code @Acuff558 to understand why that might be happening. I'd also be interested to learn why you think that's happening (e.g. did you add some print statements or run it in a debugger - in other words, what exactly is the evidence that this is happening).

Comment: The first _while_ statement works as it should when it is on its own. When I write the function with both _while_ statements, however, it returns true as soon as I call `if(completesRow())`. I tried doing some debugging by printing the `count` variable, and it shows that as soon as the second _while_ statement is called, `count` automatically increments itself until it hits 4, and then returns true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215844/discussion-between-oliver-dain-and-acuff558).